# Sequelize hook firing but not changing the object

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

```
    User.addHook('beforeCreate', (user,options) => {
        console.log('hook fired');
        console.log(user);
        bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (err,salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(user.get('password'),salt, (err,hash) => {
                user.set('password',hash);
            });
        });
    });
```

I have a sequelize hook that definitely fires due to the message and user being logged. However, when referencing the database after insertion, my passwords are not hashed.

Comment: Are you sure that user.set(); function do their job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are performing an asyncronous operation (like you are), you should return a promise inside of your hook.

```
function getHash(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (err,salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(user.get('password'),salt, (err,hash) => {
        resolve(hash);
      });
    });
  });
}

User.addHook('beforeCreate', (user,options) => {
    console.log('hook fired');
    console.log(user);
    return getHash(user)
      .then(hash => user.set('password', hash))
});
```